# How to convert JArray to generic List<>

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

Via an http Post, I send html FormData to my Web Api2 controller.
The FormData contains one or more images, as well as client properties.

My front end Angular 5 service sends the `http post` (working fine):

```js
var url = this.host + 'import/MediaUpload';

return this.http.post(url, formData, options)
            .map((result: any) => result._body)
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

I would like to convert the FormData to a generic List of MediaInfo class (defined below this `MediaUpload()` method) :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MediaUpload(int projectId, int sectionId)
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.  
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider>(new InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider());
    //access form data  
    NameValueCollection formData = provider.FormData;

    List<MediaInfo> listMedia = new List<MediaInfo>();

    //dynamic jsonData = JObject.Parse(formData["MediaInfo"]); // THROWS ERROR
    JArray ary = JArray.Parse(formData["MediaInfo"]);

    foreach (var item in ary) {
        //listMedia.Add((MediaInfo)item);   // ???
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    //access files  
    IList<HttpContent> files = provider.Files;

    HttpContent file1 = files[0];
    var thisFileName = file1.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');            

    // additional file upload code removed, working fine..

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Add("DocsUrl", URL);
    return response;
}

public class MediaInfo
{
    public string PatientID { get; set; }
    public string PatientFirstName { get; set; }
    public string PatientLastName { get; set; }
    public string PatientUID { get; set; }
    public string PatientDOB { get; set; }
    public string ExamDate { get; set; }
    public string ExamDevice { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    public string Eye { get; set; }
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public int CSIInstanceID { get; set; }
    public int MediaNo { get; set; }
    public string Procedure { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
}
```

I thought I could do something like :

```
 listMedia.Add((MediaInfo)item;
```

But I'm missing the correct conversion somewhere.

Comment: Try `listMedia.Add(item.ToObject<MediaInfo>());`

Comment: @Equalsk - That was the ticket ! I was so close while debugging within the foreach(). THANKS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a `JObject` to a type of your choosing with the `.ToObject<T>()` method.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1_1.htm

In this case you want your code to look like this:

```
listMedia.Add(item.ToObject<MediaInfo>());
```

Comment: if you have a moment to review this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172762/converting-an-ashx-web-handler-to-web-api-2 (thanks for your troubles)

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert it directly into the desired type provided `formData["MediaInfo"]` returned well formed JSON.

```
List<MediaInfo> listMedia = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MediaInfo>>(formData["MediaInfo"]);
```

Comment: also works just as well, as "MediaInfo" is well form JSON. Thanks.